# monaca localkit with the cloud IDE are not connecting to my remote server

Tags: android, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I have an application, which ought to be tested on an android device, using onsen framework in Monaca Localkit. if i should test each of my html file with my browser (chrome or Mozilla), i will definitely get back the result (connection to a remote server, through a given URL) I am expecting...but, after trying to build my apk file, either with the monaca localkit or through the cloud ide, the apk file (already installed on an android device won't carry out its operation...even on the availability of internet...cos i am on same network)....while even trying to test the app on the monaca emulator, nothing is happening still....and this is my code

```
<html ng-app = "myapp">
  <head>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-cookies-1.0.0rc10.js"></script>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src = "js/toast.js"></script>

  </head>
    <body ng-controller = "empcontroller">
<ons-navigator>
   <ons-page>

<div class="container">
  <section id="content">
    <form action="">
      <h1>Login Form</h1>
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" ng-model="fname" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" ng-model="lname"/>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</div>
      <div>    

        <input type = "button" value = "LOGIN" ng-click = "insertdata()" id = "butt"/>        
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">The Title</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
</body>

       <script>
  var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
  app.controller('empcontroller', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.insertdata=function(){
    console.log("triggered");

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "url",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: {username: $scope.fname, pswd: $scope.lname}
})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var mssg = data.MESSAGE;
        iqwerty.toast.Toast(mssg);
        console.log(data);      
        if ( data.RESULT === 1) {

          window.location.href = 'homes.html';
        } else {
          $scope.errorMsg = "Login not correct";
        }
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.errorMsg = 'Unable to submit form';
      })

  }});</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Did you utilize the whitelist plugin and add your endpoint?

Comment: yes, i did that...and i used the *...so, it can allow any domain

Comment: <allow-navigation href= " * "/>
  <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>

Comment: Well, Onsen is simply a UI framework and will not impact any external calls.  Monaca could but doesn't do that.  The issue will be with a cross domain policy somewhere - usually in Cordova.